# Have different graphics drivers for different computers with different GPUs?

Tags: gpu, ubuntu-16.04, display-driver, lubuntu

EDIT: The hard drive/usb stick in question is supposed to have the graphics drivers beforehand so it can take advantage of the in-system graphics solution.

I'm trying to make a Linux stick running Lubuntu 16.04 run on ALL SORTS of computers, here's an example.

- Computer 1: Intel i7-7700HQ/nVidia GTX 1080
- Computer 2: Intel Core 2 Duo T7250/Intel GMA 4500M
- Computer 3: AMD Ryzen 7 1800X/AMD RX 460
- Computer 4: Intel i7-7600/Intel HD Graphics 530

These computers are from different generations that use different graphics and different processors. The objective here is to get any fully-fledged Linux system to be able to go between these computers while still remaining usable, assuming that you already have the drivers on-board for the computer you'll transplant it into.

While in theory you can boot across all devices with native resolution (and boot up on Computers 2 and 4 with no problem, because they have on-board graphics), how can you get the stick to boot up with the right drivers??

<s>To be clear: Imagine the USB Stick is an ACTUAL HARD DRIVE/SSD. The drive isn't a LiveUSB made with Unetbootin or a similar utility, it is made by using the install CD to put the OS on there.</s>

Comment: Errr, solving this problem (drivers for hardware combinations that can't be known at install time, only when booting) is 95% of what makes something a "LiveUSB" (or LiveCD).

Comment: That's not the point. The point of this 'project'/hypothetical is to be able to have a mobile platform that you can use on computers that you have access to on a regular basis. i.e school, work, home. I get that you can boot w/out drivers to native resolution, but what's the fun in that? You can't really play games, and Steam absolutely REFUSES to work without nVidia drivers.

Comment: Yes that's possible.  And usually carries the "LiveUSB" description.  What is it about LiveUSB that you think is undesirable / you are looking to avoid?  Or are you simply looking for a LiveUSB based on Ubuntu, so you can use Ubuntu package manager and commands you are familiar with?

Comment: We should probably take this to chat, but what's the difference between a hard drive that moves between compatible systems and a hard drive that is meant to be permanent/stationary, aside from when a new computer is needed? To me, what was undesirable about LiveUSB was the 4GB limit, and having EVERYTHING accessible from Windows (i.e, a mad 3-yo could nuke my LiveUSB by deleting anything including the casper-rw file, whereas with my current configuration, he can only delete files on the go-between partition.)

Comment: There is no 4GB limit on LiveUSB.  The difference between LiveUSB and a permanent (non-portable) install, is that LiveUSB has to keep a lot of drivers up to date, not just the ones for the PC it's currently running on.  Concerning "accessible from Windows", that depends on what filesystem you use for the LiveUSB.  You will need a partition recognized by BIOS in order to boot, but the rest of the disk can be in any format.  Another OS can still reformat your disk (this can't be prevented) but would not be able to see or delete individual files.

Comment: So how would you go about adding drivers to the system that it'd pick 'n' choose from, or letting the user enable drivers @ startup?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62698/discussion-between-epsi-kun-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: This hypothetical is something I've actually done. Repeatedly. The twist? Most "just works" Linux distros do this out of the box. I currently have a Mint installation on a portable USB3 hard drive. So long as you use  MESA and OSS graphics drivers X.org should auto detect the correct drivers every time it launches. As will udev and the kernel (hotplug too, if you're using a distro that old). The biggest issue will be wifi and printer support. Some printers and wifi adapters just aren't supported. Others you have to hunt down firmware/kernel modules for.

Comment: If the distro expects you to specifically configure network interfaces or module loading or whatever instead of providing automated configuration for those, _then_ you might have a hard time with it.

Comment: Have _you_ ever had trouble with network interfaces? I'm aware that drivers can be an issue, but I've personally had issues with it.